# Dryer plug different from wall connection

Tags: electrical, dryer, laundry

I have a new out building with a laundry room.  The wall plug in the new laundry room is not the same as the plug on the dryer.  Do I need a new dryer or can I get a new cable for the dryer?

Here is the dryer connection:

[image]

And here is the wall plug.

[image]

Comment: Upvoted for clear pictures even if it is a duplicate!

Comment: Yes,  a good question despite the dup.

Comment: Yes, Your dryer has the old, dangerous NEMA 10 cord, which has no safety ground.  Your house has the correct NEMA 14, with ground added.   You can easily swap dryer cords; your dryer manual (online) even has a procedure for that.  Be sure to to remove the bootleg bond, which on the old cord attached the metal chassis to NEUTRAL *facepalm*.